# parseFloat for multiple entries with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a category page, where I display different products. In each product I have a section displaying **Was Price**, **Save Price** and **New Price**. Just to illustrate the structure of the **Was Price**:

```
<p class="old-price">
    <span class="price-label">Was</span>
    <span class="price" id="old-price-65848">
        <span class="price">
            <span class="currency">£</span>
        </span> 
    </span>
</p>
```

Currently on product page using jQuery I can get the was price and convert it into a number:

```
var oldPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('.old-price .price .price').first().text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);
```

And it all works fine on product page where you have only one **Was Price** block. However when I go to category page I have multiple blocks using the same structure and the same class the above code picks up only the first block and ignores the rest. This can be easily shown using:

```
console.log(oldPrice, "%");
```

How can I amend the code so it will pick up all the `Was Price` on the category page?

***Edit:***

I've managed to map the old Price and the Save price using the bellow code. However I am trying to execute math function where the condition is :

```
var oldPrices = jQuery('.old-price .price .price').map(function(){
    return parseFloat(jQuery(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);
```

}).get();

```
var specialPrices = jQuery('.special-price .price .price').map(function() {
    return parseFloat(jQuery(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);
```

}).get();

```
var youSave = specialPrices / (oldPrices / 100);
```

Unfortunately it returns NaN value

PS: All the prices are dynamically generated.

Thanks

Comment: "This can be easily shown" because it has an obvious `.first()` in the middle...

Comment: What are you expecting to do with the new "oldPrice" value(s)?   You can get them in an array, but then what?   How do you match up the old values with the new values? Or is that not important?

Comment: @freedomn-m if I remove .first() it will calculate all the Was prices.

Comment: Basically the logic is to convert to number and then do some math calculation using the new price to show the discount in percentage.

Comment: It seems like your original question was answered and the edit is a new question. May I suggest that you mark the answer here and ask a new question? That said, `specialPrices[0]` is how you should be accessing individual numbers for a calculation. Try more `console.log()` outputs to see.

Comment: I agree with @JeremyLarter - you've taken the **answer** that was provided to your question and used it to change the question incorporating that answer.  Please accept the provided answer to the original question and, if needed, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map it to get an array:

```
var oldPrices = jQuery('.old-price .price .price').map(function(){
    return parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);
}).get();

console.log(oldPrices);
```

That's said, you'd have better to set a `data-*` attribute to handle old price specific to each element, e.g: `<p class="old-price" data-old-price="12345">`.

And btw, your snippet seems unrelevant with your posted HTML markup, there is no old price value to retrieve there except maybe regarding the ID attribute.